# UIScrollview zoomToRect center of currently visible view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIScrollView displaying a image.  I want to programmatically zoom in to the a rect somewhere near the center (doesn't have to be exact) of the currently visible area.  How would I get the coordinates of this rect to use with zoomToRect? Note that this image could be already zoomed in and only showing a fraction of the scrollView content area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The the X and Y position of that image are relative to the scrollview's `contentSize`. The area shown on screen is defined by the scrollview's `contentOffset`.

You then take the position of your scrollview on screen and the position of the selection rectangle on your screen.

Finally you need to do rather simple maths (a few additions/subtractions) for both X and Y using the above values.

Answer (score 0):

Grab `UIImageView`'s `frame` and call `insetBy(dx:dy:)`:

> Returns a rectangle that is smaller or larger than the source
>   rectangle, with the same center point.

- From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454218-insetby)

Here's a quick visualisation in a PlayGround:

```
let blueSquare = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
let yellowSquare = UIView(frame: blueSquare.frame.insetBy(dx: 100, dy: 100))
blueSquare.backgroundColor = .blue
yellowSquare.backgroundColor = .yellow
blueSquare.addSubview(yellowSquare)
```

Will result in this:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to get the frame of the currently visible area?  I don't think I want to get the frame of the UIImage because I might be zoomed in already.

Comment: Gotcha. The scrollView complicates it a bit yeah. Then perhaps grab the bounds of the scrollView? It depends on your use case really. Do you want to zoom to the visible part of the image, if so take a look at [meaning-matters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447238/3947107).